# Portuguese proverb 'another coin, another carousel ride'

Tags: proverbios

I'm trying to find exact formulation of Portuguese proverb that would convey the message of *new day, new try at things*.
I only heard it briefly in conversation, but the metaphor was something along the line of *another coin, another carousel ride*.

Comment: new try at things?? This is very little to go on.

Comment: It must be an European Portuguese thing, then. It's very clear what they are asking about - it's from local fairs, carousels, boxcars, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The formulation is almost an *ipsis-verbis* translation of what you have:

> Mais uma moedinha, mais uma voltinha.

It's a common saying in Portugal, and has the simple metaphorical meaning that you sensed: "pay another coin, ride the carousel again" - repeating an attempt, having another go, etc.

It's a typical phrase used by carousel ride owners when calling folks to ride:

> Vai partir, vai mais uma...
> Mais uma moedinha, mais uma voltinha...
> Vai rodar, vai andar...
> As crianças não pagam, mas também não andam.

Comment: I am so happy you could identify this. Mas não vejo como a frase quer dizer: convey the message of new day, new try at things.

Comment: @Lambie With the carrousel, even if we already rode it we can pay another coin to ride again; and again; and again. In the same way, if yesterday we tried something, today is a new day and we can try again; and tomorrow too; etc. This is the similarity that I see. The saying itself carries an implication of _repeating_, of doing-again (in this case trying); and not of having the _opportunity_ to try again, in the sense of changing (yesterday you tried A, but today is a new day and you get the opportunity to try B instead!).

Comment: Riding again and again, is not trying new things.